# Как завершить процесс в ubuntu?

Tags: linux, unix

Как завершить процесс в ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Надо запустить терминал и выполнить команду

```
kill process_id
```

где process_id - это номер процесса. Этот номер можно получить с помощью команды

```
ps
```

Answer (score 6):

Вариант 1) В терминале вводите

> sudo killall -9 название процесса
>
> sudo kill -9 ид процесса

Вариант 2) В терминале вводите

> sudo apt-get install htop
>
> htop
>
> Выбираем нужный процесс, и жмем F9

Вообще существует множество вариантов и манов на этот счет, я привел Вам более популярные

Answer (score 4):

Только не всегда процесс убъётся таким образом! По хорошему, лучше использовать

`kill -<signal> <PID>`

либо по названию процесса

`killall -<signal> <name>`

Answer (score 2):

По хорошему процесс следует завершать сигналом 2(SIGINT) или 15(SIGTERM) и если уж не помогает тогда 9(SIGKILL).

Сигнал 2 посылается программе связанной с терминалом при нажатии Ctrl+C, есть ещё запасная комбинация Ctrl+\, посылающая сигнал 3(SIGQUIT), который, если не перехватывается, делает дамп памяти процесса (чтобы потом посмотреть в отладчике).

Сигнал 15 посылается процессам при завершении работы системы или смены runlevel и по-умолчанию если не указан другой в командах kill и killall, по нему программа может быстренько сохранить важные данные и удалить временные файлы, если настроит перехват. Так же перехват сигнала 2 используется для завершающих действий перед выходом.

Сигнал 9 нельзя перехватить, поэтому его следует использовать в крайних случаях, когда программа зависла и не реагирует на обычные сигналы.

Answer (score 1):

pkill "<шаблон>"
Убьет все процессы с таким именем

Answer (score -4):

Убиваем процесс -9 убивает железно :)

```
kill -9 PID
```

Comment: Вы удивитесь! Но нет. Зомби-процесс даже это не убьёт.

Comment: @D-side [sigkill всегда работает (возможно не сразу), если у вас есть разрешение убить процесс](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5642/1321), а [зомби по определению уже мёртв — убивать некого](https://askubuntu.com/a/427222/3712)

Comment: @jfs если целью "завершения процесса" является освобождение занятых им ресурсов, то не столь важно, мёртв процесс или нет -- ресурсы он может продолжать занимать. Но да, термин "убъёт" тут неуместен, скорее уместен "уничтожит".

Comment: @D-side прочтите мой ответ по ссылке: зомби процесс *уже* завершился. Всё что осталось это прочитать его статус.

Comment: @jfs и у него всё ещё есть запись в таблице процессов, pid и (косвенно) привязанные по pid ресурсы.

Comment: @D-side к чему вы это говорите? Вы знаете что я знаю о записи в таблице процессов (она явно упомянута в моём ответе). Какое отношение *"косвенно привязанные по pid ресурсы"* имеют к тому, что в ответ на *"железно убьёт"* (что верно—прочтите первую ссылку), вы написали *"Зомби-процесс даже это не убьёт"* (зомби уже мёртв — прочтите вторую ссылку).

Comment: @jfs а вы, вестимо, не читаете что я пишу: "Но да, термин "убъёт" тут неуместен, скорее уместен "уничтожит"." Потому что на практике задача "завершить процесс" может быть связана с ресурсами, которые могут висеть и на зомби. Поэтому на практике решения с `kill -9` может быть недостаточно. На что, собстна, первый комментарий указывал изначально, с одной терминологической ошибкой, которую я уже исправить не могу, т. к. это комментарий.

Comment: @D-side то что вы ошиблись — не страшно — все ошибаются. Проблема, что вы тень на плетень пытаетесь навести (переопределяя что фраза "завершить процесс" означает вместо того чтобы сразу признать ошибку. *"Зомби-процесс даже это не убьёт"* это ошибка и нечего юлить и демагогию разводить.

Comment: @jfs "переопределяя"? А вы знаете, какое именно определение ТС имел в виду и будут иметь в виду другие читатели? Я не ввожу своё, я указываю на одну из трактовок. Ошибку в формулировке я признал уже дважды. Ещё раз: *Но да, термин "убъёт" тут неуместен, скорее уместен "уничтожит".* В общем случае, если возникает задача "завершить процесс", `kill -9` может быть недостаточно. Вот и всё.